# Kivy - AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture' object has no attribute 'pos'

Tags: python, kivy

Im creating a multitouch application using python, the window launches as predicted and everything is working until i touch somewhere inside the window, then the touchpoint gets displayed with a circle and the window crashes.

The window should display all the touchpoints using a circle without crashing.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse

# Define a custom widget class that tracks multitouch events
class TouchTracker(Widget):

    # Override the on_touch_down method to draw a circle for each touch
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # Set the color to random
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, mode='hsv', group=str(touch.uid))
            # Draw a circle with the touch coordinates and radius
            d = 30
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d), group=str(touch.uid))

    # Override the on_touch_move method to update the circle position for each touch
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # Update the color to random
        self.canvas.get_group(str(touch.uid))[0].hsv = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        # Update the circle position with the touch coordinates
        self.canvas.get_group(str(touch.uid))[1].pos = (touch.x - 15, touch.y - 15) # Changed [0] to [1]

    # Override the on_touch_up method to remove the circle for each touch
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # Remove the color and the circle from the canvas
        self.canvas.remove_group(str(touch.uid))

# Define a custom app class that uses the TouchTracker widget
class WindowApp(App):

    # Override the build method to return the TouchTracker widget as the root
    def build(self):
        return TouchTracker()

# Run the app
WindowApp().run()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include debugging information (i.e., what you tried). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Stack Overflow FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from random import random
class MEllipse(Widget):
    rgba = ListProperty([1,1,1,0])
    size = (30, 30)
class TouchTracker(Widget):
    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        self.widget = self.ids.ellipse
        self.d = self.widget.size[0]
    def randrgba(self):
        return [random() for i in range(3)]
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.widget.pos =  (touch.x - self.d / 2, touch.y - self.d / 2)
        self.widget.rgba = (*self.randrgba(),1)


    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.widget.pos = (touch.x - 15, touch.y - 15)
        self.widget.rgba = (*self.randrgba(),1)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.widget.rgba = (0,0,0,0)

kv = '''
<TouchTracker>:
    MEllipse:
        id:ellipse
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:self.rgba
            Ellipse:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
'''
class WindowApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return TouchTracker()

WindowApp().run()
```